# Problem with expanding using-declaration with C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I tried to get my head some of the new possibilities with pack expansion in C++17 and ran into a problem which I don't understand.
I created a Derived class which inherits from a set of Base class templates.

Then I tried to import all base classes constructors into the and add a method which accesses a constant of a base class.
However, I get the following error when I try to compile.

> ```
> error: expected primary-expression before '...' token    23 |      
> return mValue == Base<M, tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>::value
> ```

Compilation works find if I either comment the import of the base class constructors or comment the method.
Is there something which prevents me to have both?

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template <size_t N, typename... Types>
struct Base
{
    static constexpr size_t value = N;
};

template <typename Tuple, typename Indices>
struct Derived;

template <typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
struct Derived<Tuple, index_sequence<Is...>> : public Base<Is, std::tuple_element_t<Is,Tuple>... >...
{   
    // Works if following line is commented
    using Base<Is, tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>::Base...;

    template<size_t M> bool check() const
    {
      return mValue == Base<M, tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>::value;
    }

    size_t mValue;
};

template <typename... Types>
struct Test : public Derived<tuple<Types...>, make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Types)>>
{};

int main ()
{
    using MyType = Test<int, float, float>;
    MyType test;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [gcc bug 79094](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79094). The program is well-formed, clang and icc accept it.

msvc accepts the simple version in the gcc bug report, but rejects this slightly more complex one (which is more similar to your example):

```
template <typename>
class U { };

template <class... Args>
struct X : U<Args>... 
{
    using U<Args>::U...;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I went crazy. I checked with wandbox with the newest version before posting, but selected gcc again.

Comment: @the_summer Yeah, do what we did before this feature - have a linear inheritance chain and bring each one in one-at-a-time.